# Sending Fluent Bit Logs from On-Premise K8s Cluster to Amazon CloudWatch failed

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, fluent-bit, kubernetes-cluster, on-premise2cloud

I have a VM outside of AWS cloud where K8s cluster exists. I am using latest version of `Fluent-bit` to send logs from the cluster to Amazon `CloudWatch`. However, I am seeing the below errors in the pod logs.

[image]

Note - I have added the access id and secret key as env variables in the FluentBit's DaemonSet and I am able to connect to AWS cloud. Previously I was getting error for shared credentials file. I believe that the token is needed to set as env var.

[FluentBit](https://github.com/fluent/fluent-bit) ConfigMap edited with below [OUTPUT] for `cloudwatch_logs`.

```
[OUTPUT]
    Name cloudwatch_logs
    Match   *
    region ap-south-1
    log_group_name /<aws/cloudwatch/log-group-name>
    log_stream_prefix from-fluent-bit-
    auto_create_group On
```